Coupon Collector Problem when obtaining a coupon is not equally likely
The standard Coupon collector problem -
There are n distinct types of coupons that come along with cereal boxes (obtaining each type of coupon is equally likely ). Find the expected number of boxes to collect at least 1 coupon of each type.
We can simply solve this problem recursively and the answer we obtain is $n(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-2}+...+\frac{1}{1})$
Now I was wondering ,how do we solve this problem when the probability of obtaining each type of coupon is not the same .Lets say we obtain coupon of type 1 with probability $p_1$, type 2 with $p_2$ and so on .How do we proceed to solve this problem elegantly ? I tried but couldn't form any recursion in this case .

Elegant solutions usually come from symmetries of the problem.  When you ruin the symmetry you ruin the elegant solution.  I think you are stuck with a full Markov chain analysis.

There's a result at the bottom of the Extensions and Generalizations section of the coupon collector Wikipedia plot summary.

See "The Coupon Collector's Problem" by Ferrante and Saltalamacchia, pdf here: https://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf
